# What is getScenarioPath and getScenarionResourceFolder?

Tags: php

I am looking at someones project and keep getting this line:

`$resource_folder = getScenarioResourceFolder(getScenarioPath($scenario));`

I cannot find any function that he implemented under those two names - **getScenarioResourceFolder** and **getScenarioPath**.
I started wandering that maybe the name Scenario has something to do with $scenario variable being in those functions. I know it might sound dumb, but I do not know what else to think.

Does anyone know about these function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know these:

1. You can search the function:
   https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=getScenarioPath if no
   result, That is must be user-defined function.
2. You can check yourself by using

   ```
    if (function_exists('getScenarioPath')) {
        ...
     } else {
        ...
     }
   ```

Comment: Thanks I know about php.net/function_name, but I was suspicious since could not find any implementations ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure those are user-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

These are clearly custom functions that have been written in.

The simplest solution would be to GREP your entire system for getScenarioResourceFolder - you are looking for a .php file.

If you can't grep or don't know how, then it's time to go digging. Open any PHP files that are related to that project and look for getScenarioResourceFolder().

If you really don't have it, then you'll have to get in touch with the original architect of the project.